# Is there a way to not select a reference category for logistic regression in SPSS?

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, spss

When doing logistic regression in SPSS, is there a way to remove the reference category in the independent variables so they're all compared against each other equally rather than against the reference category?

Comment: Please, provide more details about what you're doing and what do you want to do( if it's possible with some code ). And please, if you decided to put some code, use the tools that are available to do it instead of just placing code in text format. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you have a categorical predictor variable, the most fundamental way to encode it for modeling, sometimes referred to as the canonical representation, is to use a 0-1 indicator for each level of the predictor, where each case takes on a value of 1 for the indicator corresponding to its category, and 0 for all the other indicators. The multinomial logistic regression procedure in SPSS (NOMREG) uses this parameterization.

If you run NOMREG with a single categorical predictor with *k* levels, the design matrix is built with an intercept column and the *k* indicator variables, unless you suppress the intercept. If the intercept remains in the model, the last indicator will be redundant, linearly dependent on the intercept and the first *k*-1 indicators. Another way to say this is that the design matrix is of deficient rank, since any of the columns can be predicted given the other *k* columns.

The same redundancy will be true of any additional categorical predictors entered as main effects (only *k*-1 of *k* indicators can be nonredundant). If you add interactions among categorical predictors, an indicator for each combination of levels of the two predictors is generated, but more than one of these will also be redundant given the intercept and main effects preceding the interaction(s).

The fundamental or canonical representation of the model is thus overparameterized, meaning it has more parameters than can be uniquely estimated. There are multiple ways commonly used to deal with this fact. One approach is the one used in NOMREG and most other more recent regression-type modeling procedures in SPSS, which is to use a generalized inverse of the cross-product of the design matrix, which has the effect of aliasing parameters associated with redundant columns to 0. You'll see these parameters represented by 0 values with no standard errors or other statistics in the SPSS output.

The other way used in SPSS to handle the overparameterized nature of the basic model is to reparameterize the design matrix to full rank, which involves creating *k*-1 coded variables instead of *k* indicators for each main effect, and creating interaction variables from these. This is the approach taken in LOGISTIC REGRESSION.

Note that the overall model fit and predicted values from a logistic regression (or other form of linear or generalized linear model) will be the same regardless of what choices are made about parameterization, as long as the appropriate total number of unique columns are in the design matrix. Particular parameter estimates are of course highly dependent upon the particular parameterization used, but you can derive the results from any of the valid approaches using the results from any other valid approach.

If there are *k* levels in a categorical predictor, there are *k*-1 degrees of freedom for comparing those *k* groups, meaning that once you'd made *k*-1 linearly independent or nonredundant comparisons, any others can be derived from those.

So the short answer is no, you can't do what you're talking about, but you don't need to, because the results for any valid parameterization will allow you to derive those for any other one.